# Diferença entre setImageResource e setImageDrawable

Tags: android, imageview, drawable

Para setar uma imagem no ImageView fiz da seguinte forma utilizando o `setImageDrawable`:

```
imagem.setImageDrawable(ContextCompat.getDrawable(this,R.drawable.cliente));
```

Ao pesquisar sobre o ImageView também encontrei o metodo `setImageResource` e também funcionou dessa forma:

```
 imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.cliente);
```

Porém não descobri a diferença entre os métodos e qual devo utilizar nessa situação, que dependendo de uma informação de outra activity o metodo seta a imagem correspondente.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A finalidade dos dois métodos é a mesma: atribuir o conteúdo à *ImageView*. A diferença está apenas no tipo que cada um dos métodos recebe.

- [setImageDrawable(Drawable drawable)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageDrawable(android.graphics.drawable.Drawable)) - recebe um Drawable.
- [setImageResource(int resId)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource(int)) - recebe um inteiro referente a um *resouce Id* existente na pasta `res/drawable`.

Além desses, a *ImageView* disponibiliza outros métodos com o mesmo propósito e que recebem outros tipos:

- [setImageBitmap(Bitmap bm)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)) - recebe um Bitmap.
- [setImageIcon(Icon icon)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageIcon(android.graphics.drawable.Icon)) - recebe um Icon.
- [setImageURI(Uri uri)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageURI(android.net.Uri).) - recebe um URI.

Qual se deve usar vai depender do tipo que se tem disponível na altura.

Pelo que é dado a entender é um *Resource Id* que está disponível, então deve ser usado `imagem.setImageResource(R.drawable.cliente);`. Além que, como é um `int`, é fácil passá-lo para outra Activity, como parece ser o caso.

Answer (score 2):

Do jeito que você está fazendo, nenhuma, porque você está convertendo um resource num Drawable. Mas Drawables não precisam vir dos Resources: eles podem vir de arquivos locais do aparelho, da Internet, de um XML, podem ser gerados por algum algoritmo etc.

Resumindo: setImageResource é para imagens que estão nos seus resources e setImageDrawable é para qualquer Drawable, de onde quer que tenha vindo.

Answer (score 0):

A [documentação](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageResource%28int%29) de `setImageResource` diz que ele faz a leitura e decodificação do Bitmap na thread de UI. Por isso, esse método é mais lento do que `setImageDrawable`. A documentação sugere o uso de `setImageDrawable` ao invés de `setImageResource`.

Os métodos são diferentes e `setImageDrawable` é mais performático.